# How to control the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point character for a double variable?

Tags: c, printf, double, format-specifiers

I want to print `n` number of digits after decimal while printing a number of datatype `double`. However, integer `n` must be obtained from user using `scanf()`.

```
double pi = acos(-1);
int n;
printf("\nEnter the number of decimal digits required : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

Now, how to use `printf()` to print `n` number of decimal digits of pi?

Comment: Generate the format string via `sprintf()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1/p4, for the *precision* option,

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`. After the `%`, the following
>   appear in sequence:
>
> - An optional precision that gives [...] the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point
>     character for `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, and `F` conversions, [...] The precision takes the form of a period (`.`) followed either by an
>     asterisk `*` (described later) or by an optional decimal integer; [...]

and, in paragraph 5,

> As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In
>   this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision. The arguments
>   specifying field width, or precision, or both, shall appear (in that order) before the
>   argument (if any) to be converted. [...]

So, you can use the format

```
printf("%.*f", precision, variable);
```

like

```
printf("%.*f", n, pi);
```

to use the precision `n` taken from user.